# Making ArrayList to JTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I have an

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>
```

Object, I need to display the content of this array in a JTable.

The Map - Key is the column name and Object is the data, how can I put it up?

Baiscally the Map contains multiple-rows from a table and all the rows are added to the array list, now I need to display them in a Swing application in the form of a table and perform sorting and filtering on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For datas embed your list in a [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). A [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) is best.

For columns, embed your list in a [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html). Best is a [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableColumnModel.html).

Then use the jtable [constructor to use that](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28javax.swing.table.TableModel,%20javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel%29).

Answer (score 1):

> `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>`

This sounds like the wrong model for the job, there is not really a sensible way of turning this into a single table. Perhaps you mean

```
Map<String, List<Object>>
```

This would make a lot more sense. Now one single key (the column name) is mapped to multiple values (the column values).

Comment: hmm, makes sense, let me check it this way too!!